# After the second world war, the city of Berlin was divided ______ USSR, USA and UK

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which word is the best suited one to fill the blank, and why?

> After the second world war, the city of Berlin was divided ______ USSR,USA AND UK.
>
> Options:
>
> 1. by
> 2. with
> 3. between
> 4. among

I think "between" is the best suited one, though I am not sure.  What do I need to learn for these types of questions?

Comment: I think this test is based on difference of the "between" and "among". look here: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/between-or-among . in my opinion the answer would be among.

Comment: I would also use 'among'

Comment: I think this is a bad test question. I upvoted Flak Dinenno as presumably the desired answer. But "by" is also a completely valid word to  use in the sentence. Berlin was "divided by" the victorious countries after WW2. Also, there should be a "the" before "USSR".

Comment: @Jay I was thinking the same thing. This is why I hate it when English problems are presented as statements about history, science or sometimes even math -- they frequently include answers that are indeed valid if you know enough about the material.

Comment: France is missing from the list, so the only possible answer is _by_.  See the links in my answer below for more information.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason not to use *between* here.

Comment: @tchrist Choosing _between_ instead of _by_ would imply that that only the USSR, USA and UK controlled a part of Berlin.  Do you agree that _by_ would also be grammatically correct?  If so, which do you think would be the better choice?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect my opinion that _by_ is a better answer than _between_, which as @tchrist points out, is also technically correct.  I disagree with the statement that there is "absolutely no reason," though.  A reason not to use _between_ is that _by_ makes the resulting statement more accurate (less chance of misleading the reader), but I suppose that is outside the scope of English grammar.

Comment: Another problem with the question:  It omits the three articles in the phrase "the USSR, the USA, and the UK."

Answer (score 8):

Historical context and the naming of specific nations in the question suggests that ***by*** is a better answer than *between*, in my opinion.

---

This seems to be a lesson in history more than English grammar. There were  three heads of government (US, USSR and UK) that met at the [Potsdam](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/20th_century/decade17.asp) [Conference](http://2001-2009.state.gov/r/pa/ho/time/wwii/93275.htm).  They agreed on dividing the city of Berlin into [four zones](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/special_report/1998/03/98/berlin/72088.stm) (American, British, French* and Soviet).  So, I believe the best answer is *by* rather than *between*, because it makes the statement more accurate; i.e., there would be no omission of facts with that answer (see Edit 2).

<sup>*French delegates were not at the conference, but a French zone was decided upon at the [insistence](http://2001-2009.state.gov/r/pa/ho/time/wwii/93275.htm) of the British delegates.</sup>

**Edit**:
Hypothetically, if the question was:

> After the second world war, the city of Berlin was divided ______ the USSR, USA, UK and France.

Then, the correct answer could only be *between*.  It could not be *by* in that case, because French representatives were not part of the delegation doing the dividing.

If the group of nations were less specific, e.g.:

> After the second world war, the city of Berlin was divided ______ some of the victors.

Then, as Crazy Eyes pointed out, *among* would be acceptable.  The question would be too vague though, because *by* could also be used to correctly answer to that question.

**Edit 2**:
*Between* is also technically correct, because it doesn't violate any  grammatical rules to say that something was divided but only list a subset of the things receiving a part of it.  However, explicitly listing all but one part of the group would disingenuously imply to the reader that the list is complete. Choosing *by* avoids all of that complexity though, which makes it a better choice, in my opinion.

Comment: Well, to be more specific, for the answer to be *among*, the list of countries would have to be changed to a plural noun, like "the city of Berlin was divided among the victors." But yeah, it can't be *between*, either.

Comment: @CrazyEyes yeah, I suppose I phrased the answer a little awkwardly.  Neither _between_ nor _among_ could be used unless the question was reworded.  _Victors_ could not have been used either, because that would include other countries, e.g. Canada.

Comment: Doesn't anyone find it strange to say that we can say *The cake was divided among the four friends* but we cannot say *The cake was divided among Jim, Jane, John, and Jack*, because it has to be *between*?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is definitely **BETWEEN**

---

### *between*, *among*:   meaning and use

> - Use *between* to refer to [two] (or more) things which are clearly separated.
>     *(Cambridge Dictionary)*
> - Use *among* to talk about things which are not clearly separated
>
> because they are part of a group or crowd or mass of objects.
>   *(Cambridge Dictionary)*
>
> - *Among* and *between* can suggest a relationship that is not
>     necessarily physical. *(Dictionary.com)*
> - Between also continues to be used, as it has been throughout its
>     entire history, to express a relationship of persons or things
>     considered individually, no matter how many. *(Dictionary.com)*

**Examples:**

> - Our holiday house is between the mountains and the sea. (the
>     mountains are on one side and the sea is on the other)
> - The ancient fountain was hidden among the trees. (surrounded by
>     trees)
> - among the crowd
> - between two pillars
> - They don't have much sense among them.
> - Between you and me, I don't like any of them.

**References:**
Cambridge Dictionary:  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/between-or-among
Dictionary.com: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/among
Dictionary.com: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/between
Grammar Girl:  http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/between-versus-among

Comment: Please don't use code markup. Quote markup or bold/italics is always preferred here.

Comment: If you insist :-(

Comment: There were originally four zones when Germany was divided: American, Soviet, British, and French. ([image](http://lisahistory.net/hist104/pw/images/berlinmap.gif)).  So according to the first definition that you posted, "Use between to refer to two things..." then _between_ is not correct.  But, after reading the answer from @ayteq, I'm not certain about that anymore.

Comment: Notice my slight edit.  As supported from my last bulleted definition from Dictionary.com, between can be used for individual items regardless of number

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  But, after reading more on the subject, I don't think either is the correct choice.

Comment: why,  what did you find?

Comment: @FlakDiNenno You are right that _between_ is grammatically correct but so is _by_.  I believe _by_ is the better choice though, because it makes the statement more complete/accurate with regard to its historical context.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is “between”.

It is often taught that “between” is used for 2 items and “among” for 3 or more. But this is not completely accurate. The more accurate difference is this: “between” is used when naming distinct, individual items (this can be 2, 3, or more).

[Source](http://www.espressoenglish.net/whats-the-real-difference-between-between-and-among/)

Answer (score -2):

The difference *between* **between** and **among** is that *among* refers to *more than two*, whereas *between* is limited to *only the two* sides.

Comment: Victor, you're wrong here. I also entertained this idea for a while. Make a search. (0:

Comment: But you get sand between your toes, never sand among your toes.

Comment: @snailboat - I never thought of that! Such a thought never flashed between my ears!

Comment: Between works hear. .. because toes and ears are distinct.   Even with toes, if you mean all your toes - then still at any one time,  you're talking about sand between 2 toes, and then another 2 toes, etc. ..